# Markov Switching Model MSwM with more than 2 states

Tags: r, markov

Has anyone tried running Markov Switching Model with 'MSwM' and setting more than 2 regimes? With three it does not seem to work

#### Data (r_t)

```
[1]  0.0000000000 -0.0101170400 -0.0016032060 -0.0071256520  0.0007075710 -0.0021212120  0.0021257210 -0.0013131310 -0.0003034290 -0.0014164310  0.0026342450  0.0014147130
[13]  0.0039354190 -0.0019097400 -0.0018126890 -0.0015133170 -0.0059614020 -0.0055905670  0.0049064700 -0.0009663310  0.0000509087 -0.0146609650  0.0007232900 -0.0010325250
[25]  0.0043410850 -0.0027271790  0.0031474120  0.0004114800 -0.0002056560 -0.0016455830  0.0044297930 -0.0138461540  0.0017680710  0.0021802330 -0.0063203150 -0.0039605960
[37] -0.0036633870 -0.0042021220  0.0033231350 -0.0078334470 -0.0027554050 -0.0010626990 -0.0079787230 -0.0007506700 -0.0004561060  0.0008857870 -0.0026818280 -0.0034419710
[49]  0.0012951970 -0.0012935220 -0.0024284940 -0.0154179060  0.0032967030  0.0029572840  0.0160532930  0.0049441100  0.0033689840 -0.0026115230  0.0023511810  0.0021324230
[61] -0.0034046180  0.0002135160  0.0001601020  0.0020809990 -0.0115015970 -0.0068950660  0.0070514210 -0.0066788750 -0.0012471530  0.0017916280 -0.0028181230  0.0039130430
[73]  0.0015158080  0.0000000000  0.0023243240 -0.0023189340  0.0019459460 -0.0002157960 -0.0014569390 -0.0056741420  0.0054347830 -0.0054054050  0.0010869570  0.0014115090
[85]  0.0018432180 -0.0064935060  0.0032679740  0.0043431050 -0.0008648650 -0.0011902190  0.0021666130 -0.0055129180  0.0000000000  0.0000000000 -0.0367391300 -0.0230196340
[97] -0.0600600600  0.0788891620  0.0127562640 -0.0008996850
```

#### Code

```
model=glm(r_t ~ 1)
mod = msmFit(model, k = 3, p = 1, sw = rep(TRUE, 3))
```

#### Error message

```
Error in std[i] = summary(mod1)$sigma : replacement has length zero
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the number of states. `msmFit(model, k = 2, p = 1, sw = rep(TRUE, 3))` does not work either.

The problem here is that the wrong method for `msmFit` is used. Instead of the method for `glm`, the method for `lm` objects is used because `class(model)` is `c("glm", "lm")`.

The easiest way to fix your problem is to use `lm` instead of `glm`.

Alternatively, if you prefer the `glm` method, you can explicitly call it:

```
msmFit.glm <- selectMethod(msmFit, c("glm","numeric","logical","ANY","missing","ANY"))
mod = msmFit.glm(model, k = 3, p = 1, sw = rep(TRUE, 2))
```

NOTE that the `glm` and the `lm` methods are very different! See `?"MSM.lm-class"` and `?"MSM.glm-class"` for more details.

Comment: Thanks, it works for this input. In fact it is only first 100 observations of my real data. And trying to do the same thing for whole data using `lm` doesn't help. Error `Error in solve.default(res$Hessian) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[7,7] = 0`. 

It seems there is uninvertable matrix somewhere, but isn't there some option for MSwM fixing it.